# Getting the last digit of a number without doing the base conversion

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to solve a problem and this led me to the following :
Given a base $b$ representation of a number, how can I find its last digit in another base $c$?

For example:
The number $221_{3}$ = $100_{5}$, hence the last digit of the number $221_{3}$ converted to base $5$ would be $0$.

What's an efficient way of finding the last digit?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the value of $221_3$ [modulo $5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).  In this case, we could say that
$$
221_3 = 2 \cdot 3^2 + 2 \cdot 3 + 1 \equiv 2 \cdot (-1) + 2 \cdot (3) + 1 = 5 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}
$$